# What do I need to do to make this link work in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to learn ruby and learn how to handle a while request round trip.

On my index.html.erb page I added this line:

```
<%= link_to "Alex Link", test_path(@test) %>
```

but I got an error:

```
undefined method `test_path' for #<#<Class:0x4064e80>:0x3c0b5c8>
```

As I understand it, I need to add a record to routes.rb, and then a controller.  Correct? How do I do that?

I read the explanation for this in the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), but just finding it a bit confusing doing it the first time.

Comment: The _path variables are created from routes. You can generate a controller via "rails g controller " followed by a controller name. All this is covered in most tutorials.

Comment: @DaveNewton I know I can auto-generate the controllers, but I wanted to do it by hand so I understand what is going on there.

Comment: So generate a controller and see what's different in the project. (There's a controller class.)

Comment: @DaveNewton How would the routing snippet for this look like?

Comment: Again-easiest to generate a controller, and look at the differences. But any rails tutorial will show what routes look like for a given controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your purposes (learning) `resources tests` if fine.

It also gives you other routes for free, see RESTful routes.